# How to insert multiple dropdownlistbox in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

GridView displays data from different tables so i can't do like there [enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET-2-0) or there [enter link description here](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/%E2%80%A6)

How it do dynamically?

There my code where I bind GridView:

```
        OracleCommand oracleCom = new OracleCommand();
        oracleCom.Connection = oraConnect;
        oracleCom.CommandText = "Select * From " + Session["tableNameIns"];

        OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
        DataTable tableD = new DataTable();
        tableD.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        adapter.SelectCommand = oracleCom;
        adapter.Fill(tableD);           
        tableResults.DataSource = tableD.AsDataView();
        tableResults.DataBind();
```

Examples:
1. Table Objects: dropdownlist for column object_type.
[image]
2. Table Details: dropdownlist for columns point, object, patch.
[image]
3. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check here [Editable Gridview with Textbox, CheckBox, Radio Button and DropDown List](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37207/Editable-Gridview-with-Textbox-CheckBox-Radio-Butt)

Answer (score 0):

For drop down list in grid view for editing mode you should set tag **EditItemTemplete** and binding this grid view from database you should handle **RowDataBound** event, from this event you can bind drop down list from different tables. And this all are described in the article already. 
Just one suggestion that download the source code from reference link try to debug by applying break points to understand briefly...

Comment: In this links i must give name for column with dropdownlist but gridview displays different tables with different columns so I couldn't give name in markup.

Comment: Can you appear a code how you bind your grid view and the tables and its property with its column name which you are want to show in drop down list?